# how can I install libgnome-keyring0 on ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, apt

how can I install libgnome-keyring0 on ubuntu 20.10?

Every time someone asks that question on Stack Overflow he gets asked why he needs it.

I need it because my printer driver requires it.  Canon  LBP6230dw

I found this

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libgnome-keyring0_3.12.0-1build1_amd64.deb.html

then I downloaded with wget and tried to install

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install ./libgnome-keyring0_3.12.0-1build1_amd64.deb 2>&1 | sed -e"s/^/    /"



WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.    
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgnome-keyring0 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable
                     Depends: libgnome-keyring-common (= 3.12.0-1build1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now it seems I am starting to chase down a rabbit hole of conflicting packages.